# How to set tkinter textvariable running on separate Thread?

Tags: python, multithreading, tkinter

Trying to update tkinter 'textvariable' running on a thread with 'main' function variable. I implemented a thread based solution so the code following the tkinter mainloop can run: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1835036/15409926.

Please share how I can resolve this error. If this is not the simplest method to update 'textvariable', please share alternatives.

**Code:**

```
from tkinter import *
from threading import Thread

class GUI(Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.start()

    def run(self):
        self.root = Tk()
        self.var = StringVar()
        self.var.set("Initiated")

        screen_width = self.root.winfo_screenwidth()
        screen_height = self.root.winfo_screenheight()

        width = screen_width*.12
        height = screen_height
        x = screen_width - width
        y = screen_height*.025

        self.root.geometry('%dx%d+%d+%d' % (width, height, x, y))

        label = Label(self.root, textvariable= self.var)
        label.pack()

        self.root.mainloop()

gui = GUI()

def main():
    for i in range(1000):
        gui.var.set(f'Current Iteration: {i}')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Window doesn't update:
[Tkinter window displays initial 'textvariable'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JPlNJ.png)

**Error:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 36, in <module>
    main()
  File "test.py", line 33, in main
    gui.var.set(f'Current Iteration: {i}')
AttributeError: 'GUI' object has no attribute 'var'
```

Comment: first of, don't run `tkinter` methods in separate threads. You can run all of the `tkinter` stuff not in the main thread, but don't separate out its methods to different threads, that can break it. Second directly about your issue. Put some `time.sleep` in the `main` function before starting the loop and in the loop (otherwise it is too fast) because it takes some time for the thread to start

Comment: in your example you could use `root.after(millisecond, function)` insread of `threading` - but if you have function which need more time then you should use `queue` to send new value to thread and it should use `root.after` to check if there is new value in `queue` and update value directly in thread.

Comment: @furas The real function is long-running, so using after would keep pausing the function, right?

Comment: if you run long-rinning code then it should run in separated thread and it should use `queue` to send value to thread with GUI, and this thread should use after to check periodically if there is new info in `queue` and update values in GUI - so it will update it in the same thread as GUI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most GUIs don't like to change values in widgets in separate thread.

You should rather use `queue` to send value to thread and it should use `root.after(time, function)` to run periodically function which will get value from queue and update value in GUI.

```
import tkinter as tk  # PEP8: `import *` is not preferred
from threading import Thread
import queue
import time  # simulate show program

class GUI(Thread):
    
    def __init__(self, queue):
        super().__init__()
        self.queue = queue
        self.start()

    def run(self):
        self.root = tk.Tk()
        self.var = tk.StringVar()
        self.var.set("Initiated")

        screen_width = self.root.winfo_screenwidth()
        screen_height = self.root.winfo_screenheight()

        width = int(screen_width*.12)
        height = int(screen_height)
        x = int(screen_width - width)
        y = int(screen_height*.025)

        self.root.geometry(f'{width}x{height}+{x}+{y}')

        label = tk.Label(self.root, textvariable=self.var)
        label.pack()
 
        # run first time after 100ms (0.1 second)
        self.root.after(100, self.check_queue)

        self.root.mainloop()

    def check_queue(self):
        #if not self.queue.empty():
        while not self.queue.empty():
            i = self.queue.get()
            self.var.set(f'Current Iteration: {i}')

        # run again after 100ms (0.1 second)
        self.root.after(100, self.check_queue)
        
def main():
    q = queue.Queue()
    gui = GUI(q)

    for i in range(1000):
        q.put(i)
        # simulate show program
        time.sleep(0.5)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

---

[PEP 8 -- Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)

Comment: the `width`, `height`, `x` and `y` should be converted to `int`, otherwise they seem to raise an error. Also in this particular case there is a slight issue with that the actual `for` loop finishes in a few milliseconds, while reading the queue (especially only every 100 ms) is too slow to keep up so the actual loop will finish but the counter will run for a couple of seconds

Comment: @Matiiss you are right with integer values. as for `100ms` you can try `10ms` and this is only example - real program may run slower. And you may use `while not self.queue.empty()` instead of `if not self.queue.empty():` to fast skip some values in queue.

Comment: @Matiiss - I added `int()` for windows geometry and `while not self.queue.empty()`

Comment: great, btw I actually had never thought of using `.empty` in a loop like that to quickly go through the queue so that is something I learned, unfortunately I can't up-vote twice :)

Comment: I don't see my GUI being updated with i values from the for loop. Can you confirm?

Comment: I can print the value sent by queue but I can't seem to set StringVar().

Comment: my code works for me on Linux Mint, Python 3.8. Most GUIs don't update widgets at once because it could make to many redraws when it has to change many widgets - and window may blink/flick. They wait for end of function and then they redraw all widgets in one step. Maybe it send new values very fast and it has no time to leave `while not ...empty` and it can't fininsh `check_queue` and redraw window/widgets. Maybe you need `if` instead of `while` in `while not ...empty`. OR maybe you don't uses `after` to run `check_queue` but you use `while`-loop to repeate code - and then it can't redraw it.