# How to set tkinter 'textvariable', running in separate thread, with value from queue from main thread?

Tags: python, multithreading, tkinter

Trying to update tkinter Label based on what happens in a function that follows the thread running tkinter.

The code below (from https://stackoverflow.com/a/69743264/15409926) prints the value sent via queue from the main function, but the value that's sent does not show in the GUI.

[What is shown in GUI vs Print](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3xgjE.png)

Please share how to update the text in GUI as seen in terminal.

**Code:**

```
import tkinter as tk
from threading import Thread
import queue
import time

class GUI(Thread):
    def __init__(self, queue):
        super().__init__()
        self.queue = queue
        self.start()

    def run(self):
        global label
        self.root = tk.Tk()

        screen_width = self.root.winfo_screenwidth()
        screen_height = self.root.winfo_screenheight()

        width = int(screen_width*.12)
        height = int(screen_height)
        x = int(screen_width - width)
        y = int(screen_height*.025)

        self.root.geometry(f'{width}x{height}+{x}+{y}')

        label = tk.Label(self.root, text= self.queue.get())
        label.pack()

        # run first time after 100ms (0.1 second)
        self.root.after(50, self.check_queue)

        self.root.mainloop()

    def check_queue(self):
        #if not self.queue.empty():
        while not self.queue.empty():
            text = self.queue.get()
            label.configure(text=text)
            print(text)
        self.root.after(50, self.check_queue)
        # run again after 100ms (0.1 second)

q = queue.Queue()
gui = GUI(q)

def main():
    for j in range(100):
        q.put(f'Iteration:{j}')
        time.sleep(1)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: This code runs fine on Windows. It may be a Mac OS issue

Comment: @jezza_99 so you are seeing 'Iteration:1', 'Iteration:2', etc in the tkinter window?

Comment: It is better to remove `text=self.queue.get()` from the line `label = tk.Label(self.root, text= self.queue.get())`.

Comment: Tried this @acw1668. Still have the same problem.

Comment: Then try to run GUI in main thread and `main()` in child thread instead.  Note that it works fine in my Windows environment.

Comment: It would be more complicated to run the real main() in a child thread. Seems like it could be a Mac OS issue: are you seeing 'Iteration:1', 'Iteration:2', etc. in tkinter window? Can you confirm python version?

Comment: Yes I see them as I said it works fine in my Windows 7 box running Python 3.8.12.

Comment: Any insight into how to make this work on Mac OS? @acw1668

Comment: I don't have a Mac machine :(.  Once again suggest to run `GUI` in main thread instead.

Comment: I have modified your code to run `GUI` in main thread instead.  Try [it](https://pastebin.com/wv1frc7H).

Comment: Did you try to add `self.root.update_idletasks()`?

Comment: @ae555 yes I am seeing the iteration count in the tkinter window

Comment: Worked for me. Using Python 3.12.0rc3.